# Calculating max flow in a generalized network

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, max-flow

I'm trying to find an efficient, publically available algorithm, preferably with implementation, for solving maximum flow in a generalized (non-pure) network with gains. 
All multipliers, capacities and flow values are non-zero integers.

Does such an algorithm exist, or is this problem not solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-pure"? What is the lack of normal algorithms?

Comment: Arcs can have gains, i.e. the amount of flow going into an arc can be smaller than the amount of flow coming out of it. A pure network would  only have arcs with a multiplier of 1.

Comment: So each arc can have a different multiplier? or all of them will have a same multiplier?

Comment: Each arc can have a different multiplier.

Comment: I think there is no problem to using normal flow algorithms, just when you want calculate augmenting path, select a path such that minimum multiplier along the path is maximized over all possible paths and add the flow as c*m (not just c), I think proof of correctness of this is not hard, I'll think about it later.

Comment: Hi @WanderNauta, did you ever find an algorithm or implementation for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links to some algorithms and some explication:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds-Karp_algorithm
2. http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow
3. http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=maxFlow2

This is my solution for a maximum flow : sorry for the variables name i was young then :)
http://infoarena.ro/job_detail/431616?action=view-source

 Hope it helped

Comment: It seems these are all for non-generalized networks (i.e. 'normal' ones, where every multiplier is 1).

Answer (score 0):

The first (strongly) polynomial-time algorithm was [published](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.6809) by Végh in 2013, and has since been [improved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01778) by Olver and Végh to a worst-case runtime in O((*m* + *n* log *n*) *m* *n* log(*n*^2 / *m*)). 
But I don't know of any public implementation for this algorithm.

The linked papers also contain references to earlier (weakly) polynomial-time algorithms as well as approximate algorithms, some of which may have public implementations. ([This older paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/papers/gain-scaling.pdf) by Tardos and Wayne mentions a C++ implementation.)